# Good quality icon libraries

Tags: graphics

I am looking for some well designed icon libraries either for purchase or for free.  Any suggestions?  I need vector images of various things, like rain cloud, hitchhiking thumb, briefcase, and more.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wefunction  has an awesome free set of icons http://wefunction.com/2008/07/function-free-icon-set/

This site has links to 44 free icon sets also. http://naldzgraphics.net/freebies/40-excellent-free-icon-sets-everyone-must-have/

also you can use iconfinder.com

http://www.iconfinder.com/

Answer (score 0):

Graphic River! For instance: 
http://graphicriver.net/item/mix-and-match-weather-icon-set/79928

Answer (score 0):

[Icon Dock](http://icondock.com/) has some nice sets. It's a sub-site of ndesign-studio (.com) IIRC he also does custom work.

Answer (score 0):

Dude... you seriously need to try http://www.iconfinder.com, it is a icon search engine, it is great, offer great quality icons with all sorts of sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For starters

istockphoto.com has some great packages for sale

also

www.iconshoppe.com
www.iconfactory.com/stockicons

and there is always Smashing Mag for great reviews.

www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/07/50-fresh-useful-icon-sets-for-your-next-design/